# How to resize subview in UIView that loaded with nib file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

I've tried to create custom UIView, which contains another UIView as subview. But when I loaded it with "loadNibNamed", I cannot change the frame size of subview inside the custom view.

Pictures below is how I added the view to the viewcontroller. I still can change some property of subview, but not for the "frame". How can I change the frame size in my custom view ?

Snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Disable `autolayout` in MyView.xib. Constraints from XIB file resize `redView` back.

> Go to the File inspector in interface builder, and untick "Use Auto Layout".

Comment: Thanks, it's because AutoLayout.